# 0 as a timeout in std::condition_variable::wait_for

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable, stdthread

For instance I have next code:

```
void waitForResponse(const std::optional<int64_t>& ms){
    std::unique_lock lk{_mtx};
    _cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds{ms ? *ms : 0}, []() {
            return someCondition;
        }
}
```

Is it specified in standard if I pass `0` as a duration argument? Is it equal to the next code?:

```
void waitForResponse(const std::optional<int64_t>& ms){
    std::unique_lock lk{_mtx};
    _cv.wait_for(lk, []() {
            return someCondition;
        }
}
```

Is there any overhead?

Comment: Haven't peeked into the standard, but [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) doesn't mention any specific behaviour. So we need to assume that timeout elapses immediately. Then `wait_for` requires a duration argument, so I assume you intended `wait` in second example. Under this assumption, both examples behave entirely differently, `wait` possibly waiting forever...

Comment: @Aconcagua You are totally right. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the working draft and C++11 standard section [32.6.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.condition.condvar#38) (int the working draft), `wait_for` is

> Equivalent to: `return wait_until(lock, chrono::steady_clock::now() + rel_time, std::move(pred));`

So when you are passing

`_cv.wait_for(lk, std::chrono::milliseconds{0}, []() return someCondition;}`

you are basically calling

`_cv.wait_until(lk, chrono::steady_clock::now(), []() return someCondition;}`

and according to the [timing specifications](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.req.timing#4), the function times out when `chrono::steady_clock::now()` > C_t (C_t the time point passed to the `wait_until` function), which will timeout (and thus return) basically immediately.

And so it is different to

```
_cv.wait(lk, []() {
    return someCondition;
}
```

which will block until `someCondition` is true.